# Convert date format from 20180-01-01 to 201801

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I convert the format 2018-01-01 to 201801?  This is the code I have tried

```sql
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS ( DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()) - 1, 1, 1 )
```

Comment: 201801 is not a complete date, provided the 2018 is the year. In any case `datetime` has no format, so there is nothing to change. If you are storing dates in a varchar column, then please don't.

Comment: This is something you probably want to be doing in the presentation layer, not the data layer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the date formatting options with CONVERT - the below code will make the change:

```
DECLARE @dateString varchar(10)
SET @dateString = '2018-01-01'

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(6),
    CONVERT(datetime, @dateString, 120),
    112)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ***display*** the year and month with that format with the `FORMAT` function.

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), N'yyyyMM')
```

But the result isn't a `DATE` datatype, so you won't be able to perform date functions against it. Also `FORMAT` isn't the best for performance, if you are planning on doing this millions of times.

Answer (score 0):

if this way of formatting the date we have to convert like this

```
 select concat(year('2018-01-01'),FORMAT(month('2018-01-01'), '00') )
```

or else exactly as getdate() form means

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMM')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include month and date as well, you could use

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)
```

or you can use this for year and month only

```
select left(convert(varchar, getdate(), 112),6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT operator along with CONVERT as given below. ideally, I would suggest you to store the data in proper DATE datatype. This is just yyyyMM. You have to store in CHAR field only.

```
DECLARE @test date = '2018-01-01'

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(char(8),@test,112),6)
```